# An inverse problem of lexicographic product of graphs

Tags: graphs

In graph theory, the [**lexicographic product**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_product_of_graphs) or (graph composition) $G ∙ H$ of graphs $G$ and $H$ is a graph such that

- the vertex set of $G ∙ H$ is the cartesian product $V(G) × V(H)$;
- and any two vertices $(u,v)$ and $(x,y)$ are adjacent in $G ∙ H$ if and only if either $u$ is adjacent with $x$ in $G$ or $u = x$ and $v$ is adjacent with $y$ in $H$.

Given two graphs, it is easy to obtain their lexicographic product. However the inverse process does not look so easy.

**Recognition problem:** Given a graph G, can we guess whether there exist graphs $G_1$,...,$G_k$ such that $G=G_1 ∙ ⋯ ∙G_k$ ?

I read the book "Handbook of product graphs" and wiki, that say that the **recognition complexity** of lexicographic products is polynomially equivalent to the **graph isomorphism problem**. But I don't see the corresponding algorithm.

We know that there are already polynomial algorithms for the decomposition of the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs) of a graph. But for the lexicographic product, I don't know yet if there is some algorithm or code to implement the decomposition of the lexicographic products of a graph.

- A polynomial time algorithm for finding the prime factors of Cartesian-product graphs", Discrete Applied Mathematics, 12 (2): 123–138, doi:10.1016/0166-218X(85)90066-6, MR 0808453

Comment: Feigenbaum, J.; Schäffer, A. A. (1986), "*Recognizing composite graphs is equivalent to testing graph isomorphism*", SIAM Journal on Computing, 15 (2): 619–627, [doi:10.1137/0215045](https://doi.org/10.1137%2F0215045)

Comment: @JohnL. Sincere appreciation. I scanned the article quickly. It appears to imply a certain algorithm.